# Fill text in editBox using VBA for PowerPoint

Tags: vba, plugins, ms-office, powerpoint, ribbon

I am new to VBA power point plugin development.I have successfully added editBox in PowerPoint ribbon using CustomUI editor. Later I am facing difficulty in adding text to the editBox dynamically through VBA code.
I have seen some solutions like the flow as mentioned below:

1. Write onLoad function
2. Using GetText method, text can be entered in the editBox using Invalidate function.

But this is not happening in my case.
Can someone help/guide me for filling data in editBox of the PowerPoint ribbon using VBA code?

For reference I have posted below code. Please check.

```
Option Explicit

Dim sRename As String
Dim RibbonUI As IRibbonUI

Sub OnSlideLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
Set RibbonUI = ribbon
Set sRename = "checking"
End Sub

Sub Height_onChange(control As IRibbonControl, text As String)
    MsgBox text
End Sub

Sub Width_onChange(control As IRibbonControl, text As String)
    MsgBox text
End Sub

Sub Height_getText(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    returnedVal = sRename
End Sub

Sub Width_getText(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    returnedVal = sRename
End Sub

Sub ButtonClick()
    RibbonUI.InvalidateControl ("boxHeight")
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far and indicate which line generates an error message, if any.

Comment: @JohnKorchok I have updated code for your reference please check

Comment: You also need to provide the ribbon xml code that adds the edit box to PowerPoint.

Comment: Does `Width_getText` get called at all? Try running a MsgBox first to see if it is called, and then set `returnedVal` to a fixed string (like "hello") instead of using `sRename` - it is not used correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your support.I have found solution.
To update editBox dynamically in the ribbon either Excel/PowerPoint, we need to assign call back functions in the XML layout of PowerPoint.
The same functions have to be implemented while scripting.
In my case I have found that there is change in the VBA function name with that of XML layout  functions
As a results the call back functions are not being triggered.
I have modified them correctly, now it's working fine.